# What is the difference between the using force and without force in the forcing the signal in verilog?

Tags: verilog

What is the difference between the using force and without force in the forcing the signal in verilog?

here is a sample verilog

```
top();

wire temp;
reg temp2;

endmodule
```

And I want to force that temp and temp2 signals as below.

## case 1

```
top();

wire temp;
reg temp2;

initial begin
 top.temp = 1'b1;    
 top.temp2 = 1'b1;
end

endmodule
```

in this case, I've got some error like this.

top.slwr_w = 1'b1;
         |
ncvlog: *E,WANOTL : A net is not a legal lvalue in this context [9.3.1(IEEE)].

If I want to use like this manner without 'force'
Should I have to force only 'reg' not 'wire'?
What am I supposed to do that if I want to force to wire without force?

## case 2

```
top();

wire temp;
reg temp2;

initial begin
 force     top.temp = 1'b1;    
 force     top.temp2 = 1'b1;
end

endmodule
```

in this case, there is no error what I used with 'force'.

Q1.Firstly, I want to know what is the  difference between case1 and case2 as force manner?

Q2.and which case is the good manner?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of construct in Verilog to represent a connection: a net (usually a `wire`) and a variable (usually a `reg`). Variables have to be assigned to by `initial` or `always` blocks. Nets have to be driven by `assign` statements or `module` outputs. In case 1, you are trying to drive a net (a `wire`) from an `initial` block; this is not allowed.

`force` is used to overdrive values onto a net (eg a `wire`) or variable (eg a `reg`). This is only for testing, enabling your testbench to overdrive some internal signal in your design (eg to force and error condition or force it to be in some specific mode).

You can execute a `force` as a *sequential statement*. A sequential statement is a statement inside an `initial` or `always` block or inside a `function` or `task`. This is why case 2 compiles without an error. (The fact that a `force` statement can be sequential is essential behaviour - you probably would want to `force` a value at a certain time and perhaps `release` it later.)

So, **only** use `force` in your testbench. Only use it to overdrive some signal that is usually driven some other way, for test purposes. **Do not** use `force` in your design. Therefore,

- you should use case 1 only for your design;
- you can use either case 1 or case 2 for your testbench, but only use
  case 2 to overdrive a value (probably onto some internal connection
  in your design).

Answer (score -2):

```
top();

wire temp;
reg temp2;

reg force_temp;

assign temp = force_temp;

initial begin

 top.force_temp = 1'b1;    
 top.temp2 = 1'b1;

end

endmodule
```